# Onchange event is not working as expected in actionsupport

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>  
  <apex:inputField value="{!Sobject.field}" required="true" rendered="{!Sobject.field1 == ''}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getInfo}" rerender="frm"/>
  </apex:inputField>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

In this case, action should be triggered whenever a character is entered or deleted from the field. But for me, it is triggered only when the field is out of focus for the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onchange` event will re-evaluate the field value upon focusing in or out. You need to use one of the following events instead:

`"onkeydown", "onkeypress", "onkeyup"`